# Check if passed element is encased by a class Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I can't seem to find the answer to my question or the correct angular way to do this. I understand it's  partially subjective. I have an element that's clickable. Inside that element I also have another element that is clickable:

```
    <li (click)="route($event, d, d.isdliked)" *ngFor="let d of dList; let i = index">
        <div class="image-container" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + d.ImagePath + ')'}">
            <div class="keep-container">
                <div *ngIf="d.dliked" (click)="cantKeep()" class="liked">
                    <p>{{d.dLikes}}</p>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!d.dliked" (click)="keep(d, i)" class="not-liked">
                    <p>{{d.dLikes}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

So the first click event in the li element will route the user to another page. The other to click event's do not route anywhere. But if I click on those two inner click events I get routed to my other page when I don't want to.

So I tried this little bit of code to check to see if the element that is clicked contains the class "keep-container":

```
  route(element: Element, d: D, dIsLiked: boolean): void {
    if (!element.classList.contains("keep-container")) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dinfo']);
    }
  }
```

but this isn't working.

I tried with **element.target** of course and that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I'll keep searching.

**Main objective:** If I click on the p tag 
`<p>{{d.dLikes}}</p>` I want to check to see if it's inside the class `"keep-container"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `$event.stopPropagation()` as usually you do in javascript

```
<div *ngIf="d.dliked" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();cantKeep()">...</div>
```

Well, I like in the same .html, you can pass the $event to the function cantKeep and make the stopPropagation in the .ts

```
<div *ngIf="d.dliked" (click)="cantKeep($event)">...</div>

cantKeep(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...rest of actions..
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I got caught up in another problem. This is a clean solution and helped. Thank you!